# What is wrong in this code? Eventhe printf is not getting printed

Tags: c

What is wrong in this code even the printf is not working. but it's compiling successfully

```
#include <speex/speex.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 /*The frame size in hardcoded for this sample code but it doesn't have to be*/
 #define FRAME_SIZE 160



int main()
 {
   printf("decoding");
   char *outFile;
   FILE *fout, *fs;
   short out[FRAME_SIZE];
   float output[FRAME_SIZE];
   char cbits[200];
   int nbBytes;
   void *state;
   SpeexBits bits;
   int i, tmp;
   fout = fopen("test_40khz_mono_Q5.spx", "rb");
   if(fout == NULL){
   printf("******Error*******");
   }
   else{
   printf("*******Okay********");
   }

    fs = fopen("pcmfile","wb");
   if(fs == NULL){
   printf("****Error pcm creation****");
   }
   else{
   printf("*****pcm File created*****");
   }
state = speex_decoder_init(&speex_nb_mode);

   tmp=1;
   speex_decoder_ctl(state, SPEEX_SET_ENH, &tmp);
    speex_bits_init(&bits);

   while (!(feof(fout)))
   {
    fread(&nbBytes, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fread(cbits, 1, nbBytes, fout); //Problem area
     speex_bits_read_from(&bits, cbits, nbBytes);
     speex_decode(state, &bits, output);

     for (i=0;i<FRAME_SIZE;i++)
      out[i]=output[i];

       fwrite(out, sizeof(short), FRAME_SIZE, fs);
   }

    speex_decoder_destroy(state);
    speex_bits_destroy(&bits);
   fclose(fout);
   fclose(fs);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are 3 printf's. Please ask a real question. Clean your example up by removing all of the cruft that doesn't cause the issue. Leave the smallest part that does, and I'll be more interested to look at it.

Comment: Add some newlines to those diagnostic `printf`s - they are probably being called successfully but they won't actually reach the screen until the buffer is full, you call fflush or you print a newline, add that and newlines then tell us where it gets to

Comment: How does the program behave. Does it crash? If yes, what's the error message. Does it run successfully without writing output?

Comment: @above: It runs without giving any error. I dont know how to use cygwin for debugging. I am new to the whole environment. I think the program crashes cause of the length i have specified for nbbytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are your printf is being buffered, and your programming is probably crashing (you didn't say what happened), causing the buffer to be discarded. In *nix the output is generally line-buffered, and you'll printf will start working if you end the line, like so:

```
printf("decoding\n");
```

or you can flush the buffer explicitly (as you'll probably need to on some platforms)

```
printf("decoding\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

More than that, it's hard to help you if we don't get more info.. Is it crashing? Does it print something like 'Segmentation fault' or similar?

HTH

Comment: @above: yes it is crashing.cause of the length i have specified for nbbytes

Answer (score 1):

In order to see how far your programs get, you need to add linefeeds to your *printf* statements:

```
printf("decoding\n");
```

instead of:

```
printf("decoding");
```

Otherwise, the output is just buffered and never written to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your printf()s probably aren't appearing because your program is crashing before the buffer is flushed.

Why is it crashing?  Hard to tell, maybe the number read into nbBytes is greater than 200 so your next read is overflowing the space allocated for cbits?